# Prometheus failed to start

Tags: prometheus

I tried to install Prometheus on linux server. Below are the steps I followed but it fail when I run systemctl status prometheus command.

```
wget https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/releases/download/v2.35.0-
tar -xf prometheus-2.35.0-rc0.linux-amd64.tar.gz
mv prometheus-2.35.0-rc0.linux-amd64 /usr/local
ln -s /usr/local/prometheus-2.35.0-rc0.linux-amd64/ /usr/local/prometheus
```

2. 

```
useradd -s /sbin/nologin -M prometheus
mkdir /data/prometheus -p
chown -R prometheus:prometheus /usr/local/prometheus/
chown -R prometheus:prometheus /data/prometheus/
```

3. Create Systemd service to enable Prometheus

```
    [Unit]
    Description=Prometheus
    Documentation=https://prometheus.io/
    After=network.target

    [Service]
    Type=simple
    User=prometheus
    ExecStart=/usr/local/prometheus/prometheus --config.file=/usr/local/prometheus/prometheus.yml --storage.tsdb.path=/data/prometheus
    Restart=on-failure

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

4. 

```
systemctl status prometheus
```

**but it shows failure.**

```
prometheus.service - Prometheus
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/prometheus.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-09-26 08:36:33 UTC; 7s ago
Docs: https://prometheus.io/
Process: 2590639 ExecStart=/usr/local/prometheus/prometheus --config.file=/usr/local/prometheus/prometheus.yml --stora>
Main PID: 2590639 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Sep 26 08:36:33 ubuntu2004 systemd[1]: prometheus.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
 Sep 26 08:36:33 ubuntu2004 systemd[1]: Stopped Prometheus.
 Sep 26 08:36:33 ubuntu2004 systemd[1]: prometheus.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
 Sep 26 08:36:33 ubuntu2004 systemd[1]: prometheus.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 Sep 26 08:36:33 ubuntu2004 systemd[1]: Failed to start Prometheus.
```

Comment: Does the config file actually exist: `/usr/local/prometheus/prometheus.yml`?

Comment: Hi I slove this issue, but now I am not able to start node_exporter to a linux machine. It through error.  node_exporter.service - Node Exporter
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/node_exporter.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-10-06 06:39:16 UTC; 7s ago
    Process: 1071861 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node_exporter (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1071861 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Oct 06 06:39:16 dse-ci-test1 systemd[1]: node_exporter.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.